# cout not working with ostream header file

Tags: c++, cout, ostream

I have read that cout is an object of ostream...

But why does this code

```
#include<ostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "ostream included!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Throwing an error :-

```
practice1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
practice1.cpp:6:1: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
cout << "ostream included!" << endl;
^~~~
```

Am I going wrong in my understanding or is there some other fault?
(MinGW windows 10)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cout is declared in `iostream.h`

Comment: `#include<ostream>` -> `#include<iostream>`

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil `iostream`, not `iostream.h`

Comment: In the future, you can refer to the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ostream) website, it would have told you what was in `ostream`.

Comment: No ... I meant ostream only!
I know that will surely work with iostream, but was just trying if it works with ostream... but it didn't

Comment: @Michael Walz i beg to differ but the extension of iostream is `.h` you can safely use `#include <iostream.h>`

Comment: @AakankashaSharma: What gave you the indication that `<ostream>` would provide `cout`? We need to inform the author of the reference that it's inaccurate.

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil False. The header as specified by the Standard is named just `iostream`, no extension. If you have some compiler or library that provides a symlink or something, that's irrelevant.

Comment: I read it on cppreference...
here's the link stating "Output stream objects can write sequences of characters and represent other kinds of data. Specific members are provided to perform these output operations (see functions below).

The standard objects cout, cerr and clog are objects of this type."

link : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/

Maybe I am having a problem with my understanding :(

Comment: @AakankashaSharma: If I define `class Foo` in file `Foo.h`, it may be reasonable to assume that I also defined a global `cFoo` in that header, but not guaranteed. I should check the documentation for `cFoo` The same applies here.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks for adding that to my knowledge

Comment: @AndyG thanks for that. :')

Comment: @AakankashaSharma that's cplusplus.com, which is not cppreference. cppreference.com simply says "defined in header <iostream>", as it should.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Description

The reason of why this doesn't work is because `cout` is of type OStream but is inside the IOStream header. Hence, to get the *definition* of `cout` you need to include `iostream` library but not the `ostream` class.

#### Solution

Include `iostream` instead of `ostream`, as [OriBS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8908931/oribs) mentioned.

#### References

- Object `cout` found in [IOStream objects list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/)
- > "Including `iostream` automatically includes also `ostream`..." see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/
- > "The standard objects cout, cerr and clog are objects of this type." see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/

Answer (score 3):

You should include `iostream`

```
#include <iostream>
```